# Spring Cloud Stream Pub Sub Consumer Expecting GetTopic Permission on Topic Not On Subscriber

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-stream, spring-gcp

I have written a sample pubsub consume to cosumer messages from topic via subscription

It is expecting GetTopic Permission on topic not on subscription

```
spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.auto-create-resources=false
spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.producer.auto-create-resources=false

spring.cloud.function.definition=myCosnumer

spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.bindings.myCosnumer-in-0.consumer.subscriptionName=projects/projectId/subscriptions/my-topic-sub
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myCosnumer-in-0.destination=projects/projectId/topics/my-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myCosnumer-in-0.binder=pubsub
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myCosnumer-in-0.content-type=application/json
```

Comment: @Gary Russell. Can you please help

Comment: seems like for the consumer to start receiving the messages you need to add "pubsub.subscriptions.consume" permission on the `my-topic-sub` subscription, and "pubsub.topics.attachSubscription" permission on the `my-topic` topic

Comment: Hi @Patan did the above comment solve your issue?

Comment: @kiranmathew. My concern is that if I am reading from subscription, do we need really need access on topic as well. If we have access to subscription then it should work fine right

Comment: Hi @Patan based on my understanding you need pubsub.subscriptions.consume permission to consume messages from subscription.For more information you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control).